# save file in a folder of current directory

Tags: python

I want to create a file named current directory+folder+system date and time.
I am getting the output as-

```
D:\Komal\MyPrograms\Pkg\stemwordwww.yahoo.com42015-03-18 16-31
```

but I want to store my file named

```
www.yahoo.com42015-03-18 16-31
```

in folder `stemword` i.e require the output as

```
D:\Komal\MyPrograms\Pkg\stemword\www.yahoo.com42015-03-18 16-31
```

Code

```
def create_file(self,filename,folder):
    print 'creating file....'
    print 'file is---'
    print filename
    #Here our filename is url eg-www.amazon.in
    dir = os.getcwd()
    dir1 = os.path.join(dir,folder)
    print 'directory---'
    print dir1
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    now = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M")  
    dirPath2 = os.path.join(dir1+filename)
    dirPath = dirPath2.rstrip('\n')
    filenameCreated = dirPath+now
    print 'file is ---'
    print filenameCreated
    f = self.openfile(filenameCreated + '.txt', 'a')
    f.close()

    return filenameCreated
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an error in this line:

```
dirPath2 = os.path.join(dir1+filename)
```

It should be:

```
dirPath2 = os.path.join(dir1,filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  dirPath2 = dir1+"\"+filename
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash `"\\"`

Comment: Or even better, don't do the concatenation yourself, let `os.path.join` do it for you. It knows the directory separator, which can be different per OS.